# How to iterate through angular $scope variables with a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, for-loop, angularjs-scope

I want to iterate through an array using for loop instead of using foreach in which i m not able to break the loop. But here in for loop i getting $scope.items[i] as undefined!
here i m dynamically adding values in the array based upon the condition.

```
$scope.items= [{
        name: 'abhishek',
        credit: 1233,
        debit: 0,
        balance: 12
}];
for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.items.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.items.length);
        if ($scope.selectedName.value === $scope.items[i].name) {
            console.log($scope.items[i].name + "forif" + true);
            break;
        }
        else {
            console.log($scope.items[i].name + "forelse " + false);               
            break;                
        }
}
```

Comment: you want to iterate over `$scope.items` or `$scope.ledger` ? Because `$scope.ledger` is not defined in your piece of code

Comment: sorry for that i have done the editing @valentin

Comment: and it's still not working ? (consider starting at 0 instead of 1, and till `< $scope.items.length` since `$scope.items[$scope.items.length]` would be out of bounds.)

Comment: Several things as pointed out by other users. Start `i = 0`for your for loop, your `$scope.items` only has 1 object in its array, so there is nothing in the   `$scope.items[1]` and your `console.log($scope.items[i].name` will be undefined because again - there is nothing at index 1

Comment: Please see my answer, I think it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @abhishek did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you're starting your for loop at index 1. Arrays are 0-indexed in Javascript, so change `i = 1` to `i = 0` and you should be able to access the object(s) in your array.

Because of this your `for` loop should check if the index is *less than* the length of the array by using the less than (`<`) operator instead of (`<=`).

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements)

> JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1.

This code works fine (I don't know how you're setting your `selectedName`, but I just hardcoded it in my example:

```js
$scope.selectedName = {value: 'abhishek'};

$scope.items= [{
        name: 'abhishek',
        credit: 1233,
        debit: 0,
        balance: 12
}];

for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.items.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.items.length);
        if ($scope.selectedName.value === $scope.items[i].name) {
            console.log($scope.items[i].name + "forif" + true);
            break;
        }
        else {
            console.log($scope.items[i].name + "forelse " + false);               
            break;                
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes u are right but even if i do so i m getting the error as  $scope.items[i] as undefined

Comment: @abhishek, You have to change `i <= $scope.ledger.length` to `i < $scope.ledger.length`

Comment: I think you're mixing $scope.ledger and $scope.items perhaps?

Comment: but I dont want to compare from the first index i.e 0 after adding two rows i applying this condition and then i  m getting this error($scope.items[i] is undefined) @Alexandru-IonutMihai

Comment: yes ur code is working fine but i m still getting error. this is my code http://plnkr.co/edit/BVyXPI16D0ro6Hm2coJI?p=preview @Daniel

Comment: No that was just an example but in the link the whole scenario is different please look properly @Daniel

Comment: @abhishek This time it appears you are using `<=` instead of `<` in your for loop. This result in it trying to check index `[1]` of the array - which doesn't exist

Comment: @abhishek Glad to hear it. I added it to the answer - feel free to accept it

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over an array of *objects* therefore you need to loop through the properties of the objects inside an inner loop

We also want to avoid using `for in` loop hence the use of `Object.keys()`.

```
for (let item of $scope.items)
    for (let key of Object.keys(item))
        console.log(key, '->', item[key])
```

would display

```
    name -> abhishek
    credit -> 1233
    debit -> 0
    balance -> 12
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- You are getting error because `$scope.selectedName` is not defined in your code.
- You are trying to access `$scope.items[i].name` where value of `i` is assigned to `1` initially in the for loop. Hence, `$scope.items[1]` is not exist.

You have to change your `for loop` logic.

**Use this :**

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) { ... }
```

**Instead of :**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.items.length; i++) { ... }
```

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.items= [{
        name: 'abhishek',
        credit: 1233,
        debit: 0,
        balance: 12
    }];
    $scope.selectedName= {
        value: 'abhishek'
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.items.length);
        if ($scope.selectedName.value === $scope.items[i].name) {
            console.log($scope.items[i].name + "forif" + true);
            break;
        }
        else {
            console.log($scope.items[i].name + "forelse " + false);
            break;                
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
</div>
```